# Problema de re-renderizado de columnas con Datatables.net

Tags: javascript

Usando el pluggins javascript https://datatables.net/ en su ultima version; estoy teniendo un problema de re-renderizado.

El escenario es que he implementado este inicializador (esta en el archivo *pluggin.js*):
Destaco que tengo 2 columnas a la izquierda fijo; por ello se generan dos tablas para poder renderizar el layout correctamente esto es nativo del plugin.

(nota: este inicializador no puedo cambiarlo, forma parte del core del proyecto)

```javascript
$('.mytable').DataTable(
{
    "dom": '<"html5buttons"B>rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "lengthMenu": [
        [-1],
        ["All"]
    ],
    "autoWidth": false,
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": "300px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "ordering": false,
    "paging": false,
    fixedColumns:
    {
        leftColumns: 2
    }
});
```

luego en otro archivo *operaciones.js* modifico el contenido de una celda especifica:

```javascript
let $dstktxt = $('.dstktxt_0277'); //specific td
let diasinv = 100; //value for test purpose
if (diasinv > 0)
{
    nexttxt = ' new <span class="text-danger">(Si hay Stock)';
}
else
{
    nexttxt = ' new <span class="text-danger">(No hay Stock)';
}
$dstktxt.html(nexttxt);
```

como verán en esto puede provocar que el ancho de la tabla cambie si el contenido es mayor... automáticamente la cabecera de la tabla no se actualiza por eso según la documentación debo implementar:

```javascript
$('.mytable').DataTable().draw();
$('.mytable').DataTable().columns.adjust();
```

lo cual soluciona el problema ajustando el ancho nuevamente todas las columnas y la tabla correctamente pero tengo un efecto secundario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podrán observar en la imagen se distorsiona todo, he podido identificar algunos elementos y he llegado a la siguiente conclusión:

mi percepción es que toma la tabla e intenta reinicializarlas ... cuando lo único que quiero es volver a renderizar las columnas.

no he encontrado la solución a evitar esa distorsión.

Reproducción del Error: [Aqui](https://codepen.io/arcanisgk-the-sasster/pen/rNyoOZa?editors=1111) tambien les dejo el snipped:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      $('.mytable').DataTable({
            //"dom": '<"html5buttons"B>rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
            "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "lengthMenu": [
                [-1],
                ["All"]
            ],
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": "300px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "paging": false,
            fixedColumns:
            {
                leftColumns: 2
            }
        });
      
      $(document).off('click.plg', '#test-btn');
      $(document).unbind('click.plg', '#test-btn');
      $(document).on('click.plg', '#test-btn', (e) => {
            console.log(e.target);
            let $dstktxt = $('.dstktxt_0277'); //specific td
            let diasinv = 100; //value for test purpose
            if (diasinv > 0)
            {
                nexttxt = ' new <span class="text-danger">(Si hay Stock)';
            }
            else
            {
                nexttxt = ' new <span class="text-danger">(No hay Stock)';
            }
            $dstktxt.html(nexttxt);
            $('.mytable').DataTable().draw();
            $('.mytable').DataTable().columns.adjust();
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.6.0/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.25/b-1.7.1/b-colvis-1.7.1/b-html5-1.7.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-3.1.9/r-2.2.9/sc-2.0.4/datatables.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Example datatable.net</h1>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <table class="mytable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover t-left nowrap">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Letra A</th>
                                        <th>Letra B</th>
                                        <th>Letra C</th>
                                        <th>Letra D</th>
                                        <th>Letra E</th>
                                        <th>Letra F</th>
                                        <th>Letra G</th>
                                        <th>Letra H</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>check This</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-btn">Testing Click</button>
                                          
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="dstktxt_0277">
                                            test
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="i_text_33" placeholder="texto" class="form-control t-input t-input-hlg" data-i-name="Nombre del Campo (Texto)" data-charlimit="5">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="i-checks">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="checkbox33">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="checkbox33"><i></i>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group bootstrap-datepicker date">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_date_1" data-i-name="Nombre del Campo (Fecha)">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="b" value="radio-chk-dis">1084
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker time">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_time_1" value="" data-i-name="Nombre del Campo (Fecha)">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
  
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.6.0/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.25/b-1.7.1/b-colvis-1.7.1/b-html5-1.7.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-3.1.9/r-2.2.9/sc-2.0.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación y el escenario no se puede solucionar directamente como lo sugiera la documentación con el uso de:

```
cell($dstktxt).data(nexttxt).draw();
```

hay que recurrir a la detección de la tabla y el método `table()`;

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      var tables = $('.mytable').DataTable({
            //"dom": '<"html5buttons"B>rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
            "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "lengthMenu": [
                [-1],
                ["All"]
            ],
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": "300px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "paging": false,
            fixedColumns:
            {
                leftColumns: 2
            }
        });
      
      $(document).off('click.plg', '#test-btn');
      $(document).unbind('click.plg', '#test-btn');
      $(document).on('click.plg', '#test-btn', (e) => {
            console.log(e.target);
            let $dstktxt = $('.dstktxt_0277'); //specific td
            let diasinv = 100; //value for test purpose
            if (diasinv > 0)
            {
                nexttxt = ' new <span class="text-danger">(Si hay Stock)';
            }
            else
            {
                nexttxt = ' new <span class="text-danger">(No hay Stock)';
            }
            $dstktxt.html(nexttxt);
            var table = $(e.target).closest('table');        
            tables.table( table ).cell($dstktxt).data(nexttxt).draw();
            tables.table( table ).columns.adjust();
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.6.0/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.25/b-1.7.1/b-colvis-1.7.1/b-html5-1.7.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-3.1.9/r-2.2.9/sc-2.0.4/datatables.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Example datatable.net</h1>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <table class="mytable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover t-left nowrap">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Letra A</th>
                                        <th>Letra B</th>
                                        <th>Letra C</th>
                                        <th>Letra D</th>
                                        <th>Letra E</th>
                                        <th>Letra F</th>
                                        <th>Letra G</th>
                                        <th>Letra H</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>check This</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-btn">Testing Click</button>
                                          
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="dstktxt_0277">
                                            test
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="i_text_33" placeholder="texto" class="form-control t-input t-input-hlg" data-i-name="Nombre del Campo (Texto)" data-charlimit="5">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="i-checks">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="checkbox33">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="checkbox33"><i></i>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group bootstrap-datepicker date">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_date_1" data-i-name="Nombre del Campo (Fecha)">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="b" value="radio-chk-dis">1084
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker time">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_time_1" value="" data-i-name="Nombre del Campo (Fecha)">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
  
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.6.0/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.25/b-1.7.1/b-colvis-1.7.1/b-html5-1.7.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-3.1.9/r-2.2.9/sc-2.0.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en esta parte

```
 $('.mytable').DataTable().draw();
 $('.mytable').DataTable().columns.adjust();
```

estas creando otra vez la tabla, tienes que asignar la tabla a una variable y a esa le haces el adjust

```
mytable.columns.adjust();
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
     $('.mytable').DataTable({
            //"dom": '<"html5buttons"B>rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
            "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "lengthMenu": [
                [-1],
                ["All"]
            ],
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": "300px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "paging": false,
            fixedColumns:
            {
                leftColumns: 2
            }
        });
      
      $(document).off('click.plg', '#test-btn');
      $(document).unbind('click.plg', '#test-btn');
      $(document).on('click.plg', '#test-btn', (e) => {
            console.log(e.target);
            let $dstktxt = $('.dstktxt_0277'); //specific td
            let diasinv = 100; //value for test purpose
            if (diasinv > 0)
            {
                nexttxt = ' new <span class="text-danger">(Si hay Stock)';
            }
            else
            {
                nexttxt = ' new <span class="text-danger">(No hay Stock)';
            }
            $dstktxt.html(nexttxt);
            $(this).closest('table').DataTable().columns.adjust();
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.6.0/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.25/b-1.7.1/b-colvis-1.7.1/b-html5-1.7.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-3.1.9/r-2.2.9/sc-2.0.4/datatables.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Example datatable.net</h1>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <table class="mytable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover t-left nowrap">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Letra A</th>
                                        <th>Letra B</th>
                                        <th>Letra C</th>
                                        <th>Letra D</th>
                                        <th>Letra E</th>
                                        <th>Letra F</th>
                                        <th>Letra G</th>
                                        <th>Letra H</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                        <th>Letra I</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>check This</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-btn">Testing Click</button>
                                          
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="dstktxt_0277">
                                            test
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="i_text_33" placeholder="texto" class="form-control t-input t-input-hlg" data-i-name="Nombre del Campo (Texto)" data-charlimit="5">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="i-checks">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="checkbox33">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="checkbox33"><i></i>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group bootstrap-datepicker date">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_date_1" data-i-name="Nombre del Campo (Fecha)">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="b" value="radio-chk-dis">1084
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker time">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" name="i_time_1" value="" data-i-name="Nombre del Campo (Fecha)">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dato A1</td>
                                        <td>Dato b1</td>
                                        <td>Dato c1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato e1</td>
                                        <td>Dato f1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                        <td>Dato d1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
  
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.6.0/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.25/b-1.7.1/b-colvis-1.7.1/b-html5-1.7.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-


3.1.9/r-2.2.9/sc-2.0.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok pero el problema es que `$('.mytable').DataTable` inicializa mas de una tabla no solamente una.

Comment: ya tengo este post en el sitio oficial: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/193018

Comment: ya me auto respondí XD: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/462259/46896